# How can one solve the recurrence relation $a(n+3) = Ba(n)/n^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, frobenius-method

As the title suggests, I am looking for the solutions to the recurrence relation

$a(n+3) = B \frac{a(n)}{n^2}$.

In particular, I am attempting to solve a differential equation using the power series method and came across this formula for the coefficients. If you're curious, the differential equation is something like

$\frac{y'(x)}{x^2} - \frac{y''(x)}{x} - By(x) = 0. $

I was wondering if this were solvable in closed-form. Since I'm not an expert on recurrence relations, I didn't really know where to start (though the internet tells me nonlinear recurrence relations are usually not easy to solve).

Nevertheless, I note that if one defines $b(n) \equiv 1/\Gamma(n)$, one gets the relation $b(n+2) = \frac{b(n)}{n^2}$. This gives me hope it's solvable in terms of (scaled/shifted) gamma functions and exponentials.

Any advice?

Note: Not homework or anything, I'm just playing around with trying to find functions orthogonal to each other given the weight function w(x) = 1/x.

Comment: $e^{-x/2}y(x)$ is a solution of Airy's differential equation: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: About orthogonal functions with respect to $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)g(x)\frac{dx}{x}$, Bessel functions $J_{2n}(x)$ do the job.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(n%2B3)%3DB+a(n)%2Fn%5E2

Comment: Woah, WolframAlpha is stronger than I thought, Mr. Burton. Thanks to you and Jack! Though Jack, Wikipedia tells me the Bessel functions are orthogonal with respect to the weight function x, not 1/x. Do you have a source I could read for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check again your Gamma function understanding. If you set 
$$
b_n=Γ(n/3)^2a_n,
$$
then
$$
b_{n+3}=Γ(n/3+1)^2a_{n+3}=(n/3)^2Γ(n/3)^2\frac{Ba_n}{n^2}=\frac{B}{9}b_n
$$
which is a simple geometric sequence for the sub-sequences of every third sequence element.